# Why does it not show the added list-item? something is wrong with the single quotation marks

Tags: javascript

Why are the quotation marks not working orderly? I always get dashed lines if i use them.

```
<script>
  function addtodo(){

    todolist.innerHTML =  '
    <li class="mdl-list__item">
      <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
      Bryan Cranston
      </span>
    </li>
    '
    ;
    
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Try using ` instead of '.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan Zuzevich suggests in the comments, you need to use a back tick (i.e., `) and not single quotes. This is because [multi-line strings in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (you might see the term 'template literals') in JS need to be wrapped in backticks. If your string was single line, you could use regular quotation marks. You could also use the backslash character (i.e., \) to do this, as shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/multiline-string-variables-in-javascript/).

```html
<script>
  function addtodo(){

    todolist.innerHTML =  `
    <li class="mdl-list__item">
      <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
      Bryan Cranston
      </span>
    </li>
    `
    ;
    
  }
</script>
```